# Parsing error: Unexpected token day

Tags: lightning-aura-components, git, eslint

When trying to commit the eslint precommit is running and getting the error: `3:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token day` and prevent the commit from happen

I'm executing this example commit:

```
PS C:\Users\path> git commit -m "test"
```

The terminal display this:

```
> salesforce-app@1.0.0 precommit
> lint-staged

[STARTED] Preparing...
[SUCCESS] Preparing...
[STARTED] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Running tasks for **/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}
[STARTED] Running tasks for **/{aura,lwc}/**
[STARTED] prettier --write
[STARTED] eslint
[SUCCESS] prettier --write
[SUCCESS] Running tasks for **/*.{cls,cmp,component,css,html,js,json,md,page,trigger,xml,yaml,yml}
[FAILED] eslint [FAILED]
[SUCCESS] Running tasks...
[STARTED] Applying modifications...
[SKIPPED] Skipped because of errors from tasks.
[STARTED] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[SUCCESS] Reverting to original state because of errors...
[STARTED] Cleaning up...
[SUCCESS] Cleaning up...

✖ eslint:

C:\Users\path\force-app\main\default\aura\myComp\myComp.js
  3:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token day

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)

husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

The myComp.js has the variable `day` in it init function only:

```js
({
    createStringDate : function(rawDate) {
        let day = rawDate.getDate(); 
        let monthNumber = rawDate.getMonth()+1;
        let year = rawDate.getFullYear();
        let month = this.monthToString(monthNumber);
        return day + " " + month + " " + year;
    },
```

The code is running in the Salesforce successfully, so why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not recommended to use `let` and `const` declarations in Aura components due to compatibility issues with old browsers such as IE 11. Substitute `let` with `var` and it will work.